# Get content from database depending on the url

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get the content from the database depending on the url.
Lets say that you are on index.php then I want to get the content from the database with the entity page. My database looks like this:

```
|id | page | header | content | feature | footer |
|01 |index | header | content | feature | footer |
```

It is not the whole as it is a project that I can't show all of it, so I put in just dummy data in it here.

The config.php:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$dbhost = "dummyhost";
$dbuser = "dummyuser";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "dummy";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if(!$conn){
  die("ERROR");
}

$index = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT FROM pages WHERE page LIKE '".$url."%');
$indexRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($index);
$indexHeader = $indexRow['header'];
$indexContent = $indexRow['content'];
$indexFooter = $indexRow['footer'];
$indexfeature = $indexRow['feature'];
```

How can I do it?
I know that I can use $_GET to get some variables from the adress, but in this case I am not using any variables to go to another site. Can I still use that or am I on the right track?

Comment: Seems you are on the right track.  But you'll need to filter `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: As the question says NOT to use the query string.

> I am trying to get the content from the database depending on the url. Lets say that you are on index.php then I want to get the content from the database with the entity page.

You can get the filename called by

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$path = explode('&',$path);
$filename = substr($path[0], -4); // removing '.php'
```

You can create your SQL accordingly now and use the filename.

Comment: he just said that query string is NOT used on his site

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks, I read the line 'I am trying to get the content from the database depending on the url.' and assumed it as for query string. :) Let me know in comments if I still not got the question or request to remove the downvote. Thanks again bud.